# Unable to connect Excel workbook to IBM DB2 through ODBC driver

Tags: excel, db2, odbc

For few days now i have been trying to connect an Excel workbook to IBM DB2 server.
I downloaded the IBM ODBC driver from their website (IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - IBMDBCLI) and installed it. Then I created a System Data Sources Name with the User ID, Password, Database name, Host Name and Port Number.

Going back to Excel, when i try to get data using ODBC Driver i get this error message:

*We encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details:"ODBC: ERROR [08001] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "141.125.88.202".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10054", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001"*

I am using Windows 10 and Microsoft 365. The DB2 is a free instance

The output of my investigation on the error message was that my PC firewall prevented the connection trough the actual IP/TCP creds. i created an exception rule in the firewall settings for that But still not working.
Further investigation revealed the possibility of "[Client generated an interrupt](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-recover-sql30081n-error-message)". But that did'nt help.

Please any clue?
Anyone?

Comment: "10054" means connection-reset. Verify you are using the correct port-number, in particular . Also verify your connection string is in ODBC format. If you are using an encrypted connection, verify you are using a valid certificate and the correct port for TLS/ssl.   Nore that you should verify your connection first in the ODBCAD32 GUI (but use the correct bitness to match the bitness of your odbc driver for db2).  In other words, if you cannot connect with the odbcad32 GUI then you will be unable to connect with Excel.